# Change Control IT software - Open Source

Tags: web-applications

We are in the middle of looking for open source change control management software.  Preferably turn-key software where I just have to design some forms and then it emails appropriate people for approvals, disapprovals etc.

I have looked and looked and can't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at [OTRS](http://otrs.org)?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the ticket tracker of [Project-Open](http://www.project-open.org/) for change management. Tickets can be associated with projects. It's pretty complex, though.